# Different setting in drawn chart of exporting and original chart in highchart

Tags: highcharts, export

I used Highchart to draw some charts in my page. And i was setting some properties for my charts. I see that for download and save charts in some type, Highchart used exporting. But properties of saved charts are not same of original chart. 
for example my original chart is this:
[image]

My code is:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: color_items_array, locale: getPersianLocal()});
var chart;

$(document).ready(function() {

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        exporting: {
            allowHTML:true ,
            chartOptions: {
                xAxis: {

                    labels: {
                        align: 'top',
                    }
                },
            },
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: [{
                        textKey: 'printChart',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.print();
                        }
                    }, {
                        separator: true
                    }, {
                        textKey: 'downloadPNG',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChart();
                        }
                    }, {
                        textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChart({
                                type: 'image/jpeg'
                            });
                        }
                    }, {
                        textKey: 'downloadPDF',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChart({
                                type: 'application/pdf'
                            });
                        }
                    }, {
                        textKey: 'downloadSVG',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChart({
                                type: 'image/svg+xml'
                            });
                        }
                    }, {
                        separator: true
                    },{
                        text: 'Clinet side export to PNG',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChartLocal();
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Clinet side export to SVG',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.exportChartLocal({
                                type: 'image/svg+xml'
                            });
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        chart: {
            renderTo: conta,
            type: type,
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 120
        },
        title: {
            text: X_title,
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        // plotOptions: {
        //  column: {
        //    minPointLength: 20
        // }
        //},
        xAxis: {
            min:0,
            max:maxVariable,
            labels: {
                //rotation: rotlab,
                align: 'top',
                // align: 'center',
                autoRotation: [-45],
                autoRotationLimit: 100
            },
            categories: xAxisLabel
        },

        yAxis: yAxisVariale,

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: dataLabelvariable,
                    //  y: -5,
                    inside:false,
                    crop :false,
                    overflow :'none',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.localizationNumber(this.y);
                    },
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: [true, true],
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {

                var s = [];

                s.push('<table><tr><td style="text-align:right;" colspan="3"><b>' +
                    this.x + '</b></td></tr>');


                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {

                    s.push('<tr><td style="text-align: right;">'+
                        '<b><span style="color:'+point.series.color +'">\u25CF</span></b>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td style="text-align: right;"><b>'+point.series.name +' : </b></td>'+
                        '<td><b>' + Highcharts.localizationNumber(point.y)+'</b></td>'+
                        '</tr>');
                });

                s.push('<tr><td style="text-align:right;" colspan="3"><b>تعداد خبر : ' +
                    Highcharts.localizationNumber(this.points[0].point.NumberNews) + '</b></td></tr></table>');
                return s.join('');
            }
        },
        legend: {
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+this.name+'</b>';
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            useHTML: true,
            borderColor: '#C98657',
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
        },
        series: seris_column2,

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: scrbal,
            barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            barBorderRadius: 7,
            barBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
            buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            rifleColor: 'yellow',
            trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
            trackBorderWidth: 1,
            trackBorderColor: 'silver',
            trackBorderRadius: 7
        }


    });
});
```

My main problems are:

1) change font and size of strings(labels and titles ,..)

2) overlap of legent strings

[image]
3) when xaxis labels turn -45, labels go up.(for another example..)
[image]

I used :

```
exporting: {
        allowHTML:true ,
        chartOptions: {
            xAxis: {

                labels: {
                    align: 'top',
                }
            },
        }
```

But didn't change any thing...

How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding this option: `exporting: { scale: 1 }`

Comment: No change any thing.. :(

Comment: Are you modifying anything after chart has loaded that may be related to this? Such changes don't take effect in the export.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late for answering to this question, but I think if you change `chartOptions` to below, overlap of legend strings issue will be fixed.

```
chartOptions: {
    chart: {
        width: document.getElementById('conta').clientWidth,
        height: document.getElementById('conta').clientHeight
    }
}
```

I had same issue and it fixed by this change.